# Altering SVG shapes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button, svg, onclick

As a development from my previous task, I now want to alter my SVG shapes using
Java Script buttons using the 'onclick' procedure.

I have tried using it this way:

```
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Rotate Inner Short Arrows 45*"onclick="rotatex()"/>
<script>

function rotatex() {
document.getElementById("inner-arrow").setRotate(45,NativeCenterX,NativeCenterY)}
</script>
```

but every time I click the button nothing happens

I am a beginner in this language so would appreciate all the help I could get.

Thanks

Comment: If you just want to rotate it, use css. Toggle a class with javascript and in that class, set `rotate` and `transition` to what you want.

Comment: I will have buttons performing more than one action on each shape. Would that still work?

Comment: Are you talking about multiple animations? Check out this article on keyframe animation: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Look into css animation as a whole. I think this is a much better way to do stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
function rotatex() {
document.getElementById("inner-arrow").setAttribute("transform","rotate(45 "+NativeCenterX+" "+NativeCenterY+")")
```